# WPF alpha threshold

Tags: wpf, opacity, alpha

Is there any alpha threshold in WPF? I use brush #01000000 and on some computers it is non-transparent in regard to mouse hit testing (clicking on surface with this brush), but on some other computers it is considered as totaly transparent and mouse click-through. What is the case?

UPD1: @Alain Nope. The IsHitTestVisible property is independent of alpha click through. Here a body of the border is click throughable on all of computers:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="20" Background="#00000000" IsHitTestVisible="True"/>
</Window>
```

And here it is not (but still click-throughable on some computers - that is the question):

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="20" Background="#01000000" IsHitTestVisible="True"/>
</Window>
```

IsHitTestVisible is True in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, David Anson says in his blog here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2011/08/18/invisible-pixels-are-just-as-clickable-as-real-pixels-tip-use-a-transparent-brush-to-make-quot-empty-quot-parts-of-a-xaml-element-respond-to-mouse-and-touch-input.aspx

That you can just set it to Transparent. I had always used #01000000 like the OP. One of the commonets on David's blog says Transparent didn't work for them. I wonder if this is related to the OP's problem of #0100000 working on some computers and not others. Perhaps there is some difference other than just running it on different computers?

Comment: By default, the value is {x:Null} and it doesn't take mouse input. Setting the brush to transparent makes it respond to mouse input.

Comment: It's pity I am not near the computer where I had the problem in stable. I had two computers, the same program executed through the same ClickOnce link. One had the problem (click-through) and the other computer was OK. About the Transparent brush. My observations are that the Transparent brush is not click-throughable only in boundaries of the same PresentationSource (one window). I need to use windows with AllowsTransparency="True", and in this case only #01000000 brush work in order to make transparent but not click-throughable surface. The Transparent brush doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying Victor. The difference between clicking through one element in a WPF window to another one in the same window, versus clicking through the entire WPF window to another app behind it. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting that explicitly using the `IsHitTestVisible` property.